# Expo App - (0,s.default) is not a function. Error after exporting app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I am adding an AWS Cognito Auth function in my Expo React-native app. Everything works absolutely fine in development mode. No errors nothing at all unless I export my Expo app. After exporting my Expo app, I get an error stating `(0,s.default) is not a function`. I assume that it is related to my **aws-amplify** or **amazon-cognito-identity-js** library because it pops as soon as I click Login button which runs `Auth.signin` function. Also I tried printing the full error and it states `line:1098,column:989,URL:/data/user/0/files/.expo-internal/buldle-99A..randomNumber..`
I have gone through similar questions but none stated the error I am getting i.e. (0,s.default) is not a function. I cannot go through all the libraries in the node modules cause then it would take a decade. Also for trial and error, I am having to export my app 100s of times which isn't feasible.Can anyone let me know how can I find out what's wrong or any help? I have already tried modular exports and totally changed all the import lines.

```
import React, { useEffect,useMemo, useState,useContext } from 'react'

import {
  Text
} from 'react-native'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {AuthContext} from './component/context'

import {Amplify,Auth} from 'aws-amplify';

import {getItemAsync,setItemAsync,deleteItemAsync} from 'expo-secure-store';

import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';


import Inputs from './input1'
import Login from './login'
import AddForm from './addForm'
import DeleteEntity from './deleteEntity'
```

This is pretty much all the import part. Other files aren't giving any error. Atleast not in development. Does the error exist in `expo-secure-store`? I am having no help in finding the error since days
If you want any other info, do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had similar problem and after 2 days of searching through the internet I found this topic and actually correcting import helped!
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7679

Basically in package amazon-cognito-identity you gotta correct import:

> amazon-cognito-identity/src/utils/getRandomValues.native

correct:

> import getRandomBase64 from './getRandomBase64';

to

> import getRandomBase64 from './getRandomBase64.expo';

If this doesn't help try another ideas from the topic above however fixing import did a trick for me.

Comment: I will try this. Though it was urgent to get the work done, I shifted to python boto3 and deployed my execution code to AWS Lambda, and called it via API Gateway to perform authentication.